# Eliminating a variable with GroebnerBasis

Tags: equation-solving, groebner-bases

I have the following two hefty equations:

```
eqn1 = 110592 u^(14) - 608256 u^(12) - 147456 u^(11) y + 
   1057536 u^(10) + 602112 u^9*y + 1296 u^8 x^2 + 49152 u^8 y^2 - 
   591872 u^8 - 9216 u^7 x - 557056 u^7 y + 8856 u^6 x^2 - 
   131072 u^6 y^2 + 16384 u^6 - 15360 u^5 x - 8487 u^4 x^2 - 
   57344 u^4 + 139072 u^3 x - 80688 u^2 x^2 + 50176 u^2 - 
   146944 u x + 107584 x^2 == 0;
eqn2 = 26873856 u^(16) y^4 - 2654208 u^(16) y^2 + 
   367276032 u^(14) y^4 + 65536 u^(16) + 275816448 u^(14) y^2 + 
   902886912 u^(12) y^4 + 15592448 u^(14) + 1105416576 u^(12) y^2 - 
   5751440640 u^(10) y^4 + 61000192 u^(12) - 8064265152 u^(10) y^2 - 
   17252143344 u^8 y^4 + 668471424 u^(10) - 12938192552 u^8 y^2 + 
   52402014720 u^6 y^4 + 1938827977 u^8 + 79391817472 u^6 y^2 + 
   74950760448 u^4 y^4 - 14469805664 u^6 - 73272450048 u^4 y^2 - 
   277783609344 u^2 y^4 + 8493420928 u^4 + 20904001536 u^2 y^2 + 
   185189072896 y^4 + 3487442944 u^2 - 29359243264 y^2 + 282300416 == 
  0;
```

Please note that `x` does not appear in `eqn2`. I want to eliminate `u`. I tried (in addition to `Eliminate[]`):

```
GroebnerBasis[{eqn1, eqn2}, {x, y}, {u}]
```

including various combinations of the options: `MonomialOrder`, `Method` and `Sort`. These just run all night, without producing anything.

I got a tad optimistic when I invoked `GroebnerBasis[]` without eliminating `u`, and it came back almost immediately with a *huge* result of 43 equations and gargantuan coefficients. I then tried to work with just two equations at a time -- nada.

Any ideas how to approach this differently?

When does one know that there is no answer, vs. *Mathematica* will not come up with an answer, vs. to let it continue to chomp away?

Thank you.

Comment: "a huge result of 43 equations and gargantuan coefficients" - I would venture that this is part of the reason the elimination of `u` is taking quite a while.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you have 2 equations of the variables: x,y,u. To eliminate u, it takes one equation. This leaves one equation of two variables. But you can not solve a single equation for two variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `Resultant`?  The result is very large so not posted (noticed I removed the =0 from both expressions):

```
eqn1 = 110592 u^(14) - 608256 u^(12) - 147456 u^(11) y + 
   1057536 u^(10) + 602112 u^9*y + 1296 u^8 x^2 + 49152 u^8 y^2 - 
   591872 u^8 - 9216 u^7 x - 557056 u^7 y + 8856 u^6 x^2 - 
   131072 u^6 y^2 + 16384 u^6 - 15360 u^5 x - 8487 u^4 x^2 - 
   57344 u^4 + 139072 u^3 x - 80688 u^2 x^2 + 50176 u^2 - 
   146944 u x + 107584 x^2;
eqn2 = 26873856 u^(16) y^4 - 2654208 u^(16) y^2 + 
   367276032 u^(14) y^4 + 65536 u^(16) + 275816448 u^(14) y^2 + 
   902886912 u^(12) y^4 + 15592448 u^(14) + 1105416576 u^(12) y^2 - 
   5751440640 u^(10) y^4 + 61000192 u^(12) - 8064265152 u^(10) y^2 - 
   17252143344 u^8 y^4 + 668471424 u^(10) - 12938192552 u^8 y^2 + 
   52402014720 u^6 y^4 + 1938827977 u^8 + 79391817472 u^6 y^2 + 
   74950760448 u^4 y^4 - 14469805664 u^6 - 73272450048 u^4 y^2 - 
   277783609344 u^2 y^4 + 8493420928 u^4 + 20904001536 u^2 y^2 + 
   185189072896 y^4 + 3487442944 u^2 - 29359243264 y^2 + 282300416;

Resultant[eqn1, eqn2, u]
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that `Resultant` was using the same backend as `GroebnerBasis`, but apparently they are different enough.